# Make local notification not show in notification center by default

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

Is there a way to not make my notifications show in notification center by default?

My app is an Alarm based app so I Fire multiple local notifications to simulate an alarm. By default if i go to setting and select my app I see Show in Notification Center checked. Is there any way I can configure my app so its default behaviour is to have this option unchecked ?

Comment: **My app is an Alarm based app so I Fire multiple local notifications to simulate an alarm** instead of this you can add sound to local notification?

Comment: But wouldnt the period be less than 30 seconds? I need it to stay on for 5 minutes or so when app is in background

Comment: you can use UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger

Comment: Can you please elaborate how is that better than using UNCalendarNotificationTrigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way around it,though not ideal you can remove all notifications using this method however this requires the user to interact with the notification recieved.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
```